# Regex for matching pattern within quotes

Tags: java, regex

I have some input data such as

> some string with 'hello' inside 'and inside'

How can I write a regex so that the quoted text (no matter how many times it is repeated) is returned (all of the occurrences).

I have a code that returns a single quotes, but I want to make it so that it returns multiple occurances:

```
String mydata = "some string with 'hello' inside 'and inside'";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)+'");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
while (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, the regexp generating service :)

Comment: Just remove the `+` and replace your `if` with a `while`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find all occurences for me:

```
String mydata = "some '' string with 'hello' inside 'and inside'";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'[^']*'");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
while(matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Output:

> ```
> ''
> 'hello'
> 'and inside'
> ```

Pattern desciption:

> ```
> '          // start quoting text
> [^']       // all characters not single quote
> *          // 0 or infinite count of not quote characters
> '          // end quote
> ```

Comment: Thanks taky. although i am pretty sure this is gonna fail if there are apostrophes ('s or s') in the sentence.

Comment: @samach321 it will not work if apostrophes in the sentence. You should escape it and change parsing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should fit your requirements:

```
\'\w+\'
```

Comment: It should probably be `'[^']*'`

Answer (score 0):

`\'.*?'` is the regex you are looking for.